# SQL Server Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 16 creating SharePoint SSO database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sharepoint, single-sign-on

I'm using a web application (SharePoint) to create a database for Microsoft Single Sign On. Every attempt to create the database is giving a 'login failed' style error. For testing purposes I am using the same account on the SharePoint web application and timer service, Microsoft SSO Service, and in the 'Manage Server Settings for Single Sign-On' page in SharePoint.

The two SQL Server errors being logged are:

> Login failed for user 'blah'

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 16.

The Windows Server event log error show the same 'Login failed' message with the word 'master' in the data section.

I have tried:

- Giving the user sysadmin permission on SQL Server
- Changing the default database to one where the user has db_owner permission as well as setting it to 'master'
- Making the user local administrator on the SQL Server

The comments in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx) on the SQL Protocols blog state that:

> State=16 means that the incoming user
>   does not have permissions to log into
>   the target database...  This can also
>   happen if for example the default
>   database for user FOO is not online
>   (for example the database is marked
>   suspect).

I think I've covered the permissions and SharePoint is using the databases so they shouldn't be marked suspect.

Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Are you still getting the same error state after making the user a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, or did the error state number change at that point?

Comment: The error state number is always 16, whether the user is in the sysadmin role or not.

Comment: can you run SQL profiler and see what sql command causes the error? perhaps it will give you more details on error context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now appears to be resolved. I had to log in to the SharePoint server as the SSO service account, as described by [Frank Grossmann](http://cs.grossmann.com/blogs/fg/archive/2007/09/02/setting-up-single-sign-on-in-sharepoint-2007-errors.aspx). In fact it looks as though this SQL login error is spurious and unrelated to SSO!